KVM switching shortcut on a Dell monitor
I have a Dell U3821DW monitor with built-in KVM. I installed Dell Display Manager on Windows and configured a shortcut to switch between input sources.
I want to do have a shortcut to do the same in Ubuntu, but Dell Display Manager does not run on Linux.
Is there any other way to achieve that?
Preferably run some sort of native utility that used KVM standard protocols rather than running Dell Display Manager in Wine.
Thanks.

There is a tool in the Ubuntu repos specifically for controlling monitors, which can be installed with apt install ddcutil

ddcutil communicates with monitors implementing MCCS (Monitor Control
Command  Set)

It can be used to control inputs and picture-in-picture mode, for example.
You might have to create a script with a shortcut on the desktop to get it to function as you had it in Windows, or check GitHub for a project that might make this tool more user friendly.

I'll look into that. I thought ddcutil is only for monitor stuff like resolution, refresh rate, etc but it looks like it's more than that, so maybe it can bu used for something like that.

Looked into it some - there are some "manufacturer features" being reported but there is no support out of the box. I'll try to reverse engineer something ...

After looking at it a bit more closely I figured out how to do it with ddcutil: ddcutil setvcp 60 0x1b Feature 60 is the input source. Setting it to 0x1b selects the USB-C output which is what my other PC is connected to. Maybe put that in your answer for posterity.

To set up a shortcut to run the command go to : Applications->Settings->Keyboard->View and Customize Shortcuts->Custom Shortcuts and create a new shortcut
